# How do I get a flat file out of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Right now, I'm using `mongodump` and `bsondump` to get documents out of MongoDB, then applying regexes to the documents to get the value I want. What I really want is just a flat file of, say, the email address of every user in the `users` collection, in a flat file that I can then manipulate with `grep`, `uniq`, etc.

In MySQL, it'd be:

```
mysql < query.sql > outfile.txt
```

The **query.sql** file would be something like:

```
SELECT email FROM users;
```

But in Mongo, when I pass a .js file in, I'm still not sure how to make it output single values.

```
mongo --db test < query.js > outfile.txt
```

What would **query.js** be for the **users** collection?

Comment: This question has been answered repeated [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823990/how-to-get-mongo-command-results-in-to-a-flat-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get mongo command results in to a flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823990/how-to-get-mongo-command-results-in-to-a-flat-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use forEach to run each result through a JavaScript function and print a line in the format you want:

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(user) {
    print(user.email);
});
```

The `--quiet` command line option is also useful for removing the header lines from the output.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered repeated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823990/how-to-get-mongo-command-results-in-to-a-flat-file)

in summary

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/db --eval "var c = db.collection.find(); while(c.hasNext()) 
{printjson(c.next())}" >> test.txt
```