# How to get mongo command results in to a flat file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-query

How do I export the results of a MongoDB command to a flat file

For example, If I am to get `db.collectionname.find()` into a flat file.

I tried `db.collectionname.find() >> "test.txt"` doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

you can try the following from the command line

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/db --eval "var c = db.collection.find(); while(c.hasNext()) {printjson(c.next())}" >> test.txt
```

assuming you have a database called 'db' running on localhost and a collection called 'collection' this will export all records into a file called test.txt

If you have a longer script that you want to execute you can also create a script.js file
and just use

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/db script.js >> test.txt
```

I hope this helps

Comment: have you copy pasted this?
if yes, please double check the db name and the collection name in the query. If you have just typed it yourself, double check your spelling.

The error you are getting means that you have misspelled something...

works for me (just tested it again)

Comment: use your-moments  your-moments --eval "var c = db.profile.find(); while(c.hasNext()) {printjson(c.next())}" >> "C:\exp\test.txt"  where your-moments is the db name and profile is the collection name.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will play around that and see if i get it to work.

Comment: try also this: `mongoexport --db your-moments --collection profile --out test.txt`

Comment: It prints only [object object] in file

Comment: this answer is one year old. Maybe something changed in the version you are using. You can try to use the printjson function on a simple object from your db in the mongo console to check if it still works. If not you will have to change the printjson function

Comment: How do I do it for a remote mongo db? I tried `mongo blah.mongolab.com:33478/blah -u user -p pass --eval "my query" >> dump.txt` but it gave me `JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

Comment: @SheharyarNaseer well, the error message is rather clear. it seems you have some problem with your javascript command, or maybe the enclosing quotes. If your query is longer, I'd double check it and store it in a file and load the whole file.

Comment: This is correct, and I used this answer at first, but ran into a problem when I was doing a $not query and sending quoted fields into the query.  Without the $not I could escape the quotes but with the $not I wasn't able to get it to work.   In that case single quotes rather than double quotes around the entire eval may work better.

Comment: Worked great! Just remember to user single quotes or scape any double quote in your query.

Answer (score 28):

I know of no way to do that from the mongo shell directly, but you can get mongoexport to execute queries and send the results to a file with the -q and -o options:

```
mongoexport -h mongo.dev.priv -d models -c profiles -q '{ $query : { _id : "MRD461000" } }' -o MRD_Series1.json
```

The above hits queries the profiles collection in the models database grabbing the JSON document for _id = "MRD641000".  Works for me.

Comment: I feel this is a better answer than the currently selected one.

Answer (score 8):

Use this

```
mongo db_name --username user --password password < query1.js >> result.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this - returns a json file with the data of the query, you can change `.json` for `.txt` and other.

```
mongoexport --db products --collection clicks --query '{"createdInt":{$gte:20190101}, "clientId":"123", "country":"ES"}' --out clicks-2019.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Having missed the db needing to be the actual db in Peshkira's answer, here is a general syntax for a one liner in shell (assuming no password):

```
mongo <host>:<db name> --eval "var x = <db name>.<collection name>.<query>; while(x.hasNext()) { printjson( x.next() ) }" >> out.txt
```

I tested it both on my mac and Google cloud Ubuntu 15 with Mongo 3+.

Comment: I think that the second gone should the command key "db", not <db name>; like this: mongo <host>:<db name> --eval "var x = db.<collection name>.<query>; while(x.hasNext()) { printjson( x.next() ) }" >> out.txt

Answer (score 1):

Install MongoDB Compass, then it will have a tool to export query result to Json/CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoexport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --username youruser -p yourpass \
   -d yourDatabaseName -c collectionName --type csv \
   --fields field1,field2 -q '{"field1" : 1495730914381}' \
   --out report.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --csv --out file_name.csv -f field1,field2, field3

Comment: Including some explanation of your answer will help others that come across this solution.